# Number of grids within the price range and their width

Tags: python, grid, algorithmic-trading, trading, binance

So I'm trying to create a Binance trading grid-like structure:

My attempt:

```
grid_start = 2.5
grid_gap = 5

total_grids = 10

grids = 0

buy_grid_start = grid_start

buy_grids = []

# CALCULATE GRID
while True:
    if grids == total_grids:
        break
    else:
        grids += 1
        buy_grid_start += (buy_grid_start * grid_gap / 100)
        buy_grids.append(f"{buy_grid_start:0.3f}")

print(buy_grids)
print(f"Total grids: {grids}")
```

This just gives me 10 grids, each grid 5% above the previous grid (price).

My question is how do I get a grid structure like where you can enter Lower Price and Upper Price, and the number of grids - which will show you the percentage between each grid?

See example:
[image]

```
ATTEMPT 2: 

import math

grid_start = 1.1
grid_end = 2.2

total_grids = 10
grids = 0

buy_grid_start = grid_start
buy_grid_end = grid_end

ratio = math.pow(buy_grid_start / buy_grid_end, 1 / total_grids) * 100

buy_grids = []


# CALCULATE GRID
while True:
    if grids == total_grids:
        break
    else:
        grids += 1

        buy_grid_end == buy_grid_start * math.pow(ratio, grids)

        buy_grids.append(f"{buy_grid_start:0.3f}")

print(buy_grids)
print(f"Total grids: {grids}")
```

Output:

```
['1.100', '1.100', '1.100', '1.100', '1.100', '1.100', '1.100', '1.100', '1.100', '1.100']
Total grids: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Math.

---

**FOR LINEAR SPACING BETWEEN GRIDS**

Desired equality:

```
grid_end == grid_start + (total_grids * grid_gap)
```

Solution:

```
grid_gap = (grid_end - grid_start) / total_grids
```

Depending on how you use it, might need to replace `total_grids` with `(total_grids - 1)` in the above.

---

**FOR EXPONENTIAL ("RATIO") SPACING BETWEEN GRIDS**

That is, each grid's price is multiplied by a RATIO to the previous grid's price. Or to say it another way, starting with lower_price, multiply by ratio repeatedly.

Desired equality:

```
upper_price == lower_price * math.pow(ratio, total_grids)
```

Solution:

```
ratio = math.pow(upper_price / lower_price, 1 / total_grids)
```

Expect ratio to be slightly greater than 1. E.g. `1.05` represents an increase by `5%` each time.

For ratio as a percent:

```
ratio * 100   // %
```

To remove "1" from ratio, to show *increase*, as a percent:

```
grid_gap = (ratio - 1) * 100   // %
```

Round as desired.

NOTE: As in the Linear case, you might need `(total_grids - 1)` in formula.

Comment: Well, I get the wrong result. The formula is: Ratio = (Upper Price / Lower Price) ^ (1/n) * 100% but I am not sure how to do this in Python.

Comment: I've added a second case that should cover that.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure where to start implementing your codes. Can you just take my example and provide it with your implemented code?

Comment: Replace `buy_grid_start += (buy_grid_start * grid_gap / 100)` with `buy_grid_start *= ratio`.  I don't know from information you give, what `grid_start` should be at first. If you have trouble, Add another section to your question, where you attempt to use the above math.

Comment: Sorry if I am a little confusing! Just like the attached picture. It could be 1.1 lower price, and 2.2 upper price, and 10 grids. I'd like to have that set of geometric grids. If you read my code, you can see what I'm doing but I'm off... Also see here: https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/d5f441e8ab544a5b98241e00efb3a4ab

Comment: Sorry, I've done all I'm going to do. Good luck!

Comment: Can you please check? I have been trying since yesterday but not sure how to pull it... I edited my post with attempt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243467/discussion-between-cassano-and-toolmakersteve).